# Nested route in node / express js

Tags: node.js, express, url-routing

I attempting to configure a nested route in Express application like so:

```
app.put('api/template/:id/page/:pageID', updateTemplatePage);
```

But when my page makes the call, I get a 404 back. My log shows this:

> PUT /api/template/519537192e20b47409c46e72/page/home 404 4ms

`home` is my page ID in this case, so the call URL looks valid to me. Simpler calls, like `GET /api/template/519537192e20b47409c46e72` work just fine. How can I make this work?

Comment: So express routing problems cannot be debugged in isolation. The middleware and routing engines all interact in sometimes non-intuitive ways. Extract just a tiny 1-file app and reproduce the problem, then start adding back your middleware and routes. Almost all the time there's an out-of-order problem between middleware and your route handlers, but we need a full code snippet to diagnose this.

Comment: also set the `DEBUG=express:routes` environment variable then start your server and you will see some more verbose logging that may help.

Comment: Set up a gist with all of the routes. Also try running it in debug-brk and see if updateTemplatePage is even getting called?

Comment: updateTemplatePage is not being called

Answer (score 1):

I was missing '/' in front of the path. Should be like this:

```
app.put('/api/template/:id/page/:pageID', updateTemplatePage);
```

Thank you all for your suggestions.